# Include Nuget dependencies in my build output?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, mef

I am building a modular .NET core application that can load extensions at runtime using MEF. I have 2 projects, one is a library that I want to be able to load at runtime, then I have my main application that will do the loading.

My library project has some Nuget dependencies. In order to load my library at runtime, I need those Nuget dependencies to be available next to the library at runtime, but building using VS2017 does not include these Nuget DLLs as part of the output.

How do I get Nuget DLLs included when I build my library?

Edit: I have tried `dotnet publish` and `dotnet pack`, but both of those make me a `nupkg` file only containing my DLL and not the nuget DLLs I need with it. Also, I can't load a `nupkg` file at runtime very easily, which is why I'd like to just get the resulting assemblies themselves on their own.

For what it's worth, this is what my csproj looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>JSON.plugin</AssemblyName>
    <IncludeBuiltProjectOutputGroup>true</IncludeBuiltProjectOutputGroup>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Composition" Version="1.0.31" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\BDDGen.Types\BDDGen.Types.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: The command-line way is to to do a `dotnet publish`, not a `dotnet build`. Not sure if VS has a way to do that (surely, it must).

Comment: `dotnet publish` builds me a .nupkg file that only has my library DLL in it, nothing else.

Comment: Are you trying to embed your references in your DLL?  Maybe check out [`Costura.Fody`](https://github.com/Fody/Costura).

Comment: No, but that may be an option. I just want my DLL and the Nuget DLLs it depends on next to it.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Logan are you looking under the `publish` directory? What are its contents after running a `dotnet publish`?

Comment: @omajid I wasn't getting a `publish` directory anywhere previously, but it seems after running `dotnet clean` and then a `dotnet publish` I have all my deps in the `publish` folder like I wanted. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In order to make the build process copy all referenced dll files from NuGet packages from the cache folder into the build output, set this property inside a `<PropertyGroup>`:

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Comment: This works for nuget packages dependencies. What if I have a solution with multiple projects and I also need to include on the solution's main project, other projects' output DLLs? What I'm still missing now, even using your suggestion, are the DLLs of my two prjects that I dynamically load from the main project that doesn't directly depend on them.

Comment: If it doesn't depend on them, then they won't be copied to the output.. if you want that you'll need to add a project reference

Comment: I don't want to add a project reference since there's no "direct dependance" between the projects. Anyway I found another possible approach. I can use a Post-build event set on the dependency projects. I added a little `xcopy` script to copy the output DLLs of projects to the `bin` folder of the main project after every build.

Comment: Just what I needed on a .Net 2.0 standard project.

Comment: @CheshireCat, can you share the code you mentioned above, thanks

Comment: What file would i need to edit to do that?

Comment: The project's .csrpoj file

Comment: Thanks for this - the solution was surprisingly difficult to find. It's a pity that this isn't an setting in the Visual Studio Project Properties. It must be a common requirement, and it really shouldn't be so opaque...