# Bundle nuget packages into DLL from project to allow reuse in third party projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Let me try to explain the scenario:

I have a common libraries project which is a DLL project. This DLL is used in project #1 and project #2, referenced via the compiled DLL.

Common libraries includes several nuget packages, including Newtonsoft.Json and RestSharp.

**Whenever I add the DLL to another project, such as projects #1 and #2, I need to go to nuget and install the same two packages in each of the projects.**

I would like to be able to build my common libraries dll and have it "embed" the nuget packages in a way that makes it transparent for the client applications, in this case projects #1 and #2, without having to explicitly include them.

I believe the complexity of this is obvious if we have 10 included packages and 5 consumer projects, and we need to update packages. It is rather painful and I can't help but wonder there might be a better way to handle this.

I would prefer something native, not having to rely on external tools to merge dlls, or additional nuget packages if possible. I found a few things in stackoverflow, including this: [Include Nuget dependencies in my build output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464271/include-nuget-dependencies-in-my-build-output)
and this: [Build NuGet Package automatically including referenced dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173568/build-nuget-package-automatically-including-referenced-dependencies)

But this is not what I am looking for.

Is this even possible?

Clarification: The output of the compilation should be a single dll including my code and any nuget packages / dlls. Creating a nuget package for my dll project is viable, and as a last resort, if I can't get around this with a single DLL, I would rather have multiple separate DLLs instead of having to rely on an external tool to do the merging.

Comment: "Whenever I add the DLL to another project" How exactly do you do that? Nuget reference, direct dll reference, project reference?

Comment: Would you be ok with turning your DLL _into_ a nuget package which would need to be published to and pulled from a feed (not necessarily the public one)?

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT thank you for the clarification. I would like something native, I don't want to rely on external libraries. I will try to find an alternative. I can always copy the dlls from the packages to the output folder, but it is less organized...

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, that would be an option, as long as I can control who has access to that package. and the reference is a direct dll reference

Comment: Why don't you publish your library as a Nugget package to a feed, and your NuGet package would declare Newtonsoft and any other libraries as dependencies? This is the normal thing to do.

Comment: @mason because from what I understand, that does not generate a single DLL, but multiple.

Comment: Why do you need a single DLL? What problem are you trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: @mason it is a requirement for some of the consumers of the DLL that it is only one file.

Comment: Why is that a requirement? What problem does that requirement solve? When you get strange requirements, you must go back and make sure you understand the purpose, because it sounds like a specific solution is being dictated to solve some perceived problem, instead of dictating a problem and letting the best solution arise. Please be specific about what the problem is here.

Comment: @mason nothing is being dictated here. If it is a possibility it will be implemented through a single DLL file, if it is not a possibility an alternative solution will be used.

Comment: Alternative solution - but to what problem? What is the actual issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: @mason no one said it is a problem. No one told you they are trying to solve a problem, You are the one that keeps referring to a non existing problem. There is no problem here. The requirement is X, if doable. My question is: is X doable? It is as simple as that.

Comment: You said "alternative solution" - solutions are in response to problems. I'm here to help you, and if you want effective help it'd be best to bear with these questions for a bit so we can ultimately understand the purpose of the requirements and make sure that's addressed properly, rather than assuming the only way to get this done is to combine everything into a single DLL. So, let's get an answer to this: why do they want to combine these DLL's? What is the reason for this?

Comment: @mason I understand your point, but I do not agree with you. Your approach is "why", you want to understand the reason behind. That does not answer the question posted above. My approach is a little bit different: "why not?". Questioning the motive does not solve the problem, if you're questioning the motive you're trying to find a way to move away from that requirement. The reason behind it is not important for answering the question, just the feasibility. If it is feasible, great. If it is not feasible, we solve that problem (the lack of feasibility) by finding an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to move you away from the requirement, because the requirement is very strange and there's likely a better way to go about it. Even if it's possible to accomplish, you should still make sure you provide the why, so that you don't end up doing something completely unnecessary that could be solved in a better way. It's a [classic XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Poor Miguel gave you a nice answer, but you said their answer wasn't viable without offering any explanation as to why. That's clear evidence that you haven't provided enough context here to solve the real issue.

Comment: I would not be wanting to allow 3rd parties to repackage my proprietary DLLs into a single DLL of theirs. Especially if I strongly type my DLL to prevent this. In 20 years, it has been a nuisance to some devs who come across from other languages, but never been a real issue, that is simply how it works. Please do not even try to do this, we are all very curious as to why you would want to do this though. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think I can reproduce the situation:

[image]

You want to integrate some third-party packages into one dll, and you want all the necessary things to be in one dll, right?

## If you want this, then:

*1, If you want official native method to achieve this, **the answer is NO.***

*2, If you use 3rd party tool, then **it can be done.** But **I extremely don't recommend this.***

Here's a detailed implementation step-by-step as I give an explanation of how this idea works and why I strongly discourage it(The example on my side is a net6 dll):

###### 1' you need a tool to achieve this:

There is a tool named ['ILRepack'](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ILRepack/).

Install command:

`Install-Package ILRepack`

After that, you will be able to find the ILRepack.exe file in path:

`C:\Users\Administrator\.nuget\packages\ilrepack\2.0.18\tools`

Configure the above path to the system environment path of the machine.

###### 2' Prepare required dll files:

For example, on my side they are:

> Nuget_Bundle.dll (This is the dll of my class library which used 3rd nuget packages.)
>
> Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> RestSharp.dll

Open a new command prompt terminal, and then go to the path that stored the above dll files, then run the command:

`ilrepack /out:Merged.dll Nuget_Bundle.dll Newtonsoft.Json.dll RestSharp.dll`

After that, there will be a dll file named Merged.dll in the same directory.

You can refer this dll file in the project you want like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Add dll file references here -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\process_attach\Nuget_Bundle\Merged.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

After that, you will be able to run/debug the test project:

[image]

This is indeed possible, but I highly unrecommend it, in which case issues like Partial Merging, Version Mismatch, Binding Redirects, Inlining may occur. This method may even cause problems with VS IntelliSense. If this happens, it will make your development experience quite bad.

All in all, native methods cannot achieve merge dll requirement(or merge packages content to dll). You can use the second method to achieve this, but I don't recommend it. The classic dependency management method is more mature than this.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. #2 is not a viable solution on my side, but I appreciate the time to write that, it will for sure help others.

Comment: @MiguelMesquitaAlfaiate For the doable of the official way, I [already mentioned it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASQj8.png) in my answer. :)